# Cyclically get the GPS data

Tags: java, android, api, gps, geolocation

I am implementing the android app which uses GPS data (especially GPS time). Now I am using interface "LocationListner" in "GPSReader" class and it seems like to "listen" to the GPS data only when the coordination changes.

I am also trying to store the GPS data in global variable "gpsTime" in public class "Common" and use it from "SensorReader" class. In this class, I tried to get the GPS data cyclically such as 100 Hz, however, as I mentioned before, the data such as latitude, longitude and GPS time sometimes doesn't change because there is no change of coordination. I want to use GPS time as reference time, so want to get it cyclically such as 100 Hz. I think "LocationListner" is "passive", so is there any "positive" way that the program cyclically get GPS data by itself?

Thank you so much in advance.

Here is "GPSReader" class which includes "LocationListner".

```
package com.crowdsourcing.usgs;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

import Util.DateFormatter;


/**
 * Created by TomokazuY on 9/14/2014.
 */
public class GPSReader extends Service implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener, GpsStatus.NmeaListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private String provider;
//gpsLog, gpsTime will be passed to SensorReader
public String gpsLog;
private long gpsTime;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double altitude;
private float bearing;
private float accuracy;
private String gpsProvider;
public String nmea;

private long lastUpdate = 0;
//For global variable 
Common common;

public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
}


public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea)
{
    this.nmea = "NMEA Sentence: "+ nmea;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //For global variable
    common=((Common)getApplicationContext());

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    // the last known location of this provider
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    common.initGPSTime = location.getTime();

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        this.onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200 milli secs change
    // Both set to zero, which is the most aggressive setting.
    // You’ll get a location update if any change in location is detected at any time.
    // This setting can result in your app accessing the GPS provider as often as 50 –
    //This can drain a fully charge Samsung Galaxy S III in less than 3 hours.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0,0, this);

    locationManager.addNmeaListener(this);

    return START_STICKY;

}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
    makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location loc) {
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    altitude = loc.getAltitude();
    bearing = loc.getBearing();
    accuracy = loc.getAccuracy();
    gpsProvider = loc.getProvider();

    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currentGpsTime = loc.getTime();
    String currentGpsTimeString;
    common.gpsTime = currentGpsTime;
    currentGpsTimeString = DateFormatter.formatTimeStampM(common.gpsTime);

    common.gpsLog = ",lat:," + latitude + ",long:," + longitude + ", alt:," + altitude
            + ", accuracy:," + accuracy + ", provider:,"+ gpsProvider

            + ", GPSTime:," + DateFormatter.formatTimeStampM(common.gpsTime)
            + ", ForGraph:," + curTime + "," + currentGpsTime
            + ", NMEA:," + nmea;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSReader.this);
    }
}

// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
// Random number generator
private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    GPSReader getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return GPSReader.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public long getGpsTime() {
    return this.gpsTime;
}

//The function for gpsLog to be passed to SensorReader
public String getGpsLog() {
    return gpsLog;
}

}
```

Also here is "SensorReader" class which has cyclically loop (There is part which assigns sampling ratio).

```
package com.crowdsourcing.usgs;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import Util.DateFormatter;
import Util.FileCreator;

/**
 * Created by SusanaLauH on 9/14/2014.
 */
public class SensorReader extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

    //private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometerSensor, gyroscopeSensor, uncalGyroscopeSensor,
                   temperatureSensor, gravitySensor, lightSensor,
                   linearAccSensor, magnetSensor, uncalMagnetSensor,
                   airPressureSensor, humiditySensor, proximitySensor;

    Boolean test;
    Boolean isAccelerometer, isGyroscope, isUncalGyroscope, isMagnet, isUncalMagnet, isGravity,
            isLinearAcceleration, isTemperature, isProximity, isHumidity, isPressure, isLight;

    Boolean is1Hz, is5Hz, is50Hz, is100Hz;

    float xA, yA, zA = 0;// Accelerometer
    float xGy, yGy, zGy = 0; //Gyroscope
    float xGyu, yGyu, zGyu = 0; //Uncalibrated gyroscope
    float xGr, yGr, zGr; //Gravity
    float xLA, yLA, zLA;  //Linear Acceleration
    float xMg, yMg, zMg; //Magnetic Field
    float xMgu, yMgu, zMgu; //Uncalibrated magnetic field
    float temperature, airPressure, humidity, proximity, light;

    private long lastUpdate = 0;
    //private long lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int samplingRate = 1000; //Sampling rate = 1 Hz (units are in milliseconds)
    GPSReader gpsReader = new GPSReader();

    //Global variable
    Common common;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting reading sensors", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Global variable
        common=((Common)getApplicationContext());

        common.initSysTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        accelerometerSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        gyroscopeSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        uncalGyroscopeSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED);
        temperatureSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        gravitySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
        lightSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        linearAccSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        magnetSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        uncalMagnetSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED);
        airPressureSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        humiditySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY);
        proximitySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

        //Using DELAY_FASTEST, the sensor will try to sensor the data as fast as possible.
        //Use more system resources
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, uncalGyroscopeSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, temperatureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, gravitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, linearAccSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, uncalMagnetSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, airPressureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, humiditySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, proximitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


       isAccelerometer = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Accelerometer");
       isGyroscope =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Gyroscope");
       isUncalGyroscope =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("UncalGyroscope");
       isGravity =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Gravity");
       isMagnet =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Magnet");
       isUncalMagnet =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("UncalMagnet");
       isLinearAcceleration =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("LinearAcceleration");
       isLight =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean(":Light");
       isProximity =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Proximity");
       isPressure =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Pressure");
       isTemperature =  intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Temperature");
       isHumidity = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("Humidity");

       is1Hz = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("1Hz");
       is5Hz = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("5Hz");
       is50Hz = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("50Hz");
       is100Hz = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("100Hz");


        //Toast.makeText(this, "Frequency 1: " + is1Hz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Frequency 5: " + is5Hz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Frequency 100: " + is100Hz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (is1Hz == true){
            samplingRate = 1000;
        }

        if (is5Hz == true){
            samplingRate = 200;
        }

        if (is50Hz == true){
            samplingRate = 20;
        }

        if (is100Hz == true) {//100 Hz
            //samplingRate = 10;
            samplingRate = 5;

        }
        //Detecting accelerometer
        if (accelerometerSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Accelerometer detected with MaxRange of: " + accelerometerSensor.getMaximumRange()
                                   + " and resolution of: " + accelerometerSensor.getResolution()
                                   + " and minDelay of: " + accelerometerSensor.getMinDelay(),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No accelerometer detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Detecting gyroscope
        if (gyroscopeSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gyroscope detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No gyroscope detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Detecting temperature sensor
        if (temperatureSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Temperature Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No temperature sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

      //Detecting gravity sensor
        if (gravitySensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gravity Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No gravity sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

      //Detecting light sensor
        if (lightSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Light Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No light sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

       //Detecting magnetic field detector
        if (magnetSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Magnetic field Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No magnetic field sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

       //Detecting air pressure sensor
        if (airPressureSensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Air pressure Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Air pressure sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Detecting humidity sensor
        if (humiditySensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Humidity Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No humidity sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Detecting proximity sensor
        if (proximitySensor != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No proximity sensor detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor mSensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        //Accelerometer
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && isAccelerometer == true) {
            xA = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yA = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zA = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }

        //Gyroscope
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE && isGyroscope == true) {
            xGy = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yGy = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zGy = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }

        //-Uncalibrated Gyroscope
        //Uncalibrated sensors provide more raw results and may include some bias,
        // but their measurements contain fewer jumps from corrections applied through calibration
        //Data is without drift compensation
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE_UNCALIBRATED && isUncalGyroscope == true) {
            xGyu = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yGyu = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zGyu = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }

        //Temperature
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE && isTemperature == true) {
            temperature = sensorEvent.values[0];
        }

        //Gravity
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY && isGravity == true) {
            xGr = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yGr = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zGr = sensorEvent.values[2];
         }

         //Light
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT && isLight == true) {
            light = sensorEvent.values[0];
        }

        //Linear Acceleration
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION && isLinearAcceleration == true) {
            xLA = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yLA = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zLA = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }

        //Magnetic Field
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD && isMagnet == true) {
            xMg = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yMg = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zMg = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }
        //Uncalibrated Magnetic Field
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED && isUncalMagnet == true) {
            xMgu = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yMgu = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zMgu = sensorEvent.values[2];
        }

        //Air Pressure
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE && isPressure == true) {
            airPressure = sensorEvent.values[0];
        }

        //Humidity
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY && isHumidity ==true) {
            humidity = sensorEvent.values[0];
        }

        //Proximity
        if (mSensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY && isProximity == true) {
            proximity = sensorEvent.values[0];
        }

        //Logging data
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //long curTime = gpsReader.getGpsTime();
        //long gpsTime= common.gpsTime;
        //Get the GPS time from GPSReader
        String logTime = DateFormatter.formatTimeStampM(curTime);
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > samplingRate) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;
            String log = logTime;

                if (isAccelerometer == true){
                    log = log + ",Acc:," + xA + "," + yA + "," + zA;
                }

                if (isGyroscope == true) {
                    log = log + ",Gyro:," + xGy + "," + yGy + "," + zGy;
                }

                if (isUncalGyroscope == true) {
                    log = log + ",UncGyro:," + xGyu + "," + yGyu + "," + zGyu;
                }

                if (isGravity == true) {
                    log = log + ",Gravity:," + xGr + "," + yGr + "," + zGr;
                }

                if (isMagnet == true) {
                    log = log  + ",Mag:," + xMg + "," + yMg + "," + zMg;
                }

                if (isUncalMagnet == true){
                    log = log  + ",UncMag:," + xMgu + "," + yMgu + "," + zMgu;
                }

                if (isLinearAcceleration == true) {
                    log = log + ",Linear acc:," + xLA + "," + yLA + "," + zLA;
                }

                if (isLight == true){
                    log = log  + ",Light:," + light;
                }

                if (isTemperature == true) {
                    log = log + ",Temp:," + temperature;
                }

                if (isProximity == true){
                    log = log + ",Proximity:," + proximity;
                }

                if (isPressure == true){
                    log = log + ",AirPressure:," + airPressure;
                }

                if (isHumidity == true){
                    log = log + ",Humidity:," + humidity;

                }
                   // + ", xA:" + xA + ", yA:" + yA + ", zA:" + zA
                   //+ ", xG:" + xGy + ", yG:" + yGy + ", zG: " + zGy + ", "
                   // + ", xGu:" + xGyu + ", yGu:" + yGyu + ", zGu: " + zGyu + ", "
                    //+ ",Acc:," + xA + "," + yA + "," + zA
                   // + ",Gyro:," + xGy + "," + yGy + "," + zGy
                   //+ ",UncGyro:," + xGyu + "," + yGyu + "," + zGyu
                    //+ ",Temp:," + temperature
                    //+ ",Gravity:," + xGr + "," + yGr + "," + zGr
                    //+ ",Light:," + xA + "," + yA + "," + zA
                    //+ ",Linear acc:," + xLA + "," + yLA + "," + zLA
                    //+ ",Mag:," + xMg + "," + yMg + "," + zMg
                    //+ ",UncMag:," + xMgu + "," + yMgu + "," + zMgu
                    //+ ",Air:," + airPressure
                    //+ ",Humidity:," + humidity
                   // + ",Proximity:," + proximity

           // log = log + gpsReader.getGpsLog();

                    //+ common.gpsTime;
                 log = log   + common.gpsLog;


            FileCreator file = new FileCreator();
            file.write("Logs", log);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    //Do nothing
    }

    // To provide binding for a service, you must implement the onBind() callback method.
    // This method returns an IBinder object that defines the programming interface that
    // clients can use to interact with the service.
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //return mBinder;
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

 }
```

And "Common" class for global variable

```
package com.crowdsourcing.usgs;
import android.app.Application;


/**
 * Created by tomokazy on 9/20/14.
 */
public class Common extends Application{
    // Global
    long initSysTime;
    long initGPSTime;
    long gpsTime;
    String gpsLog;
    public void init(){
        gpsTime = 0;
        gpsLog = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the GPS updates more slowly (it's probably 1Hz on most devices) what you'll probably need to do is use the GPS time to periodically sync a 100Hz timer that keeps track of the milliseconds component, although I haven't done enough Android programming to suggest a specific way.